# What makes planar inverted F-antenna omnidirectional but doesn't make the microstrip patch antenna omnidirectional?

Tags: antenna

I see some designs without antenna substrate for PIFAs. I mean there's a patch over a ground plane meanwhile substrate is almost used in all designs of microstrip patch antennas. What's the exact and fundamental reason for PIFAs to be omnidirectional?

Comment: Would be news to me that PIFA's are omnidirectional; how should they be?

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK. It was wrong to ask the question in that way. I shouldn't have asked by generalizing. They're evolved from monopole antennas, aren't they? It's said most of them can be easily omnidirectional, whereas microstrip patch antenna is usually directional with some exceptions such as back to back mspa.

Comment: who says that? I really can't find any reason to assume they're omnidirectional. It feels very counterintuitive to assume any antenna to be omnidirectional around an axis that they're not rotationally symmetric to. I especially can't find a single radiation pattern to prove that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I found it from a part of this book -> Antenna and Wave Propagation by Sisir K. Das. P:502, Part; 11:10 it says that The PIFA is popular, talking about mobile hand set antennas, because it has a low profile and omnidirectional pattern. Additionaly I found a technical note " Planar Inverted-F Antennas (PIFA)" belongs to a Swedish company, Proant AB, says the same thing. I find a lot of articles PIFAs and their omnidirectional characteristics when I googled "Pifa omnidirectional"

Comment: hm, interesting! I found for example [this](http://www.scielo.org.co/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0012-73532015000100010) article, which says "omnidirectional", but take a look at figure 10: That's not very omnidirectional, actually, is it? That's "somewhat even, if we ignore half of the circle".

Comment: I think this really boils down to how you define your metric for "omnidirectional". I'd certainly say this doesn't look omnidirectional, but maybe the authors of the article applied a different method to define "omnidirectional"; and by their method, it is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Agreed, but much number of articles which had proper view of its radiation pattern available. I found this [link](https://arrow.tudublin.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1120&context=ahfrcart) looks better. But a question in my mind that is it really possible to get more than 0 dB (theoretically best) for an omni. Many articles which call themselves 'omnidirectional' also focus on giving their gains pointing out that they are high. Why gain matter in those, I don't get it. If it's omni, it means no matter directivity so does the gain. Doesn't it?

Comment: that is an interesting article, because just as you, I couldn't find many papers that actually delivered radiation patterns to match their omnidirectionality claim! Gain vs Omnidirectionality: You can be omnidirectional in one plane, but highly directive in another. I think that might be what you're referring to? It's hard to tell just by you citing papers I don't know :(

Comment: For example, in the linked paper: Fig. 10 shows a pretty \$\Phi\$-omnidirectional pattern in the ZY-plane, but in the XZ-plane (Fig. 11), it's a seemingly somewhat visible gain!

Comment: (I must, though, admit I'm a bit confused by their notation of these figures; I'll have to sleep over that!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for the discussion. Appreciated.